# Regarding pool integration into phantom wallet

Tags: liquiditypool

I developed my AMM smart contract and I'd like to integrate it into phantom wallet so users can use my pool for swapping.
What kind of process is needed for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to talk to Phantom directly, I don't think Stack Exchange can do anything for you unfortunately!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like phantom swaps are powered by Jupiter
Here is the docs on how you can integrate your amm into jupiter. Then Phantom will automatically pick it up at some point if it provides good rates.
https://docs.jup.ag/integrating-your-dex/integration-guidelines

[image]